# Ionic web browser cookies

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a IOS app that connects to a external website in a Iframe using wkwebview. That website is supposed to drop a cookie on the device but fails to do so on IOS devices. Has anyone experienced something similar or is there other information that I can give that would help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We ended up changing the hostname in the app.

Comment: May I know where to change the hostname for the app? I thought ionic framework app doesn't have any "hostname" unlike a domain/website?

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#hostname something like this

Comment: Hi. Are u available to further guide me on this solution? I may need this solution for one of my iframe. Thanks

Comment: Sorry this is the best I can give